# Setting up python networking in windows 8

Tags: python, networking

This a very basic question , well, I installed python 2.7.5 and set the environment variables.
Both in cygwin and in cmd when I type python, the interpreter works, but when I run a code with any address family, sat AF_INET , it says '' 'Module' object has no attribute 'af_inet''

What I think is, the module 'socket' is not installed and has to be installed. But doesn't it come along when I install the full package?

I hope this thread solves all the question regarding installing python and making it work.

Thank you!

ok , here is the code, is it really simple.

```
import socket 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'socket created'
```

Thats it. In my friends computer which runs a python 2.7 works, but I have both 2.7 and 3.2 , and it doesnt work in any of it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably named your file `socket.py`, or have another file `socket.py` on the module search path.

In this case, that module shadows the system's `socket` module and that's the error you get. That's why it's a bad idea to give modules the name of an already existing standard library module.

The full traceback should include a clue about where the module is being imported from.

Comment: it was socket.py, but even after changing it,I have the same problem, what is distutils ? I have cygwin and cmd. In cygwin both python and python3 works, that is 2.7 and 3.x even if I uninstall the files, that is because cygwin has its own python lib files. Even that shows the same error if I run in it!

Comment: @jarvis11 - You mean you still get the exact same error message as before? if so, please update your question to include the full traceback - otherwise you should probably start a new question.

Comment: I got it fixed. I deleted those socket.py files (renamed and copied ones) and opened a new folder( not in the home dir) wrote a simple socket code and it worked.